# Django: query filter for group in which user is part

Tags: django, permissions, view, django-queryset

I am trying to filter a view related to the group to which the logged in user belongs to.

Lets say we have a user who belongs to a group DOGS. I figured out how to filter for a specific that means known group name = DOGS.

**Models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

    class Customer(models.Model):
        customerName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        accountOwner = models.ForeignKey(Group, null=True, related_name='usGroup', on_delete=models.SET_NULL )
```

How do I do that in

**views.py**:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group

 @login_required
    def home(request):
        myData = Customer.objects.filter("Return only data of the group to which the user belongs".)
```

Do you have a hint? I only found solutions for filtering a specific groupname but not the property of the logged in user.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you want to obtain all the `Customer`s with as `accountOwner`, a `Group` object to which the logged in `User` belongs.

A request has a `request.user` attribute which stores the user that is logged in. We can then filter on this:

```
@login_required
def home(request):
    myData = Customer.objects.filter(accountOwner__user=request.user)
```

Note that since a `User` can belong to several groups at the same time, it is thus possible that you obtain `Customer`s that belong to different `accountOwner`s. For example if the logged in user belongs to both the DOGS and CATS group, you thus will obtain `Customer`s that belong to the DOGS group as well as `Customer`s that belong to the CATS group.

Comment: Thank you. I knew that it is easy but I didn't know the answer. What I don't get: Why can I access the user through the Foreign Key relation of 'Group'?

Comment: @kingbrain: because Django always automatically adds an implicit reverse relation. You can obtain the users of a `Group` with `some_group.user_set.all()` for example. In queries, you can thus use `user`.

Comment: @Willem_Van_Onsem: Thank you for your reply and sorry for bothering again. Am I right that this is the intrinsic concept of many-to-many-relationships? [Django Model Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#module-django.db.models)

Comment: @kingbrain: wel for any type of relation, so `ForeignKey`s, `OneToOne`s, etc. So yes indeed, this is also the case for relations you write yourself. If you thus wrote for example two models `A` and `B`, and `B` has a `ForeignKey` to `A`, then you can query `some_a.b_set.all()` to fetch the relation in reverse.